# Stripe - Is it possible edit amout before capture a charge?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

As you can see in [Stripe Api Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/python#capture_charge) to capture a charge you just need:

```
import stripe
stripe.api_key = "sk_test_whatever"

ch = stripe.Charge.retrieve("ch_whatever")
ch.capture()
```

But is it possible to edit the retrieved charge's amout before capture it?

At this point:

```
ch = stripe.Charge.retrieve("ch_whatever")  # Here you have the charge object
```

So you can see its amount

```
ch.amount
# 7000
```

I wonder if I can edit it before capture the charge. I've tried:

```
ch.amount = 9000
ch.save()
# This is what I get
InvalidRequestError: Request req_whatever: Received unknown parameter: amount
```

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Daenyth I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API docs state:

`Updates the specified charge by setting the values of the parameters passed. Any parameters not provided will be left unchanged.
This request accepts only the description, metadata, receipt_email, fraud_details, and shipping as arguments.`

You cannot update a charge amount.

Comment: That is the update charge API, there is a separate capture charge API that would allow you to edit the amount you wish to capture

Answer (score 2):

When you call the `capture charge` api you can capture an amount that is less than the requested amount. Card networks do not allow you to capture more than the amount you authorized.